# How to close a div by clicking outside anywhere?

Tags: javascript, c#

I am working on alpha.dubaiexporters.com.

```
http://alpha.dubaiexporters.com/aboutus.aspx
```

There is a go button clicking on which a search panel appears where I can perform search keyword and category.

The issue is that `after clicking on go button, search panel appears but if the user does not want to perform any search, he clicks outside anywhere but that search panel does not go.`

I tried the following code where I have written javascript code but it didn't work.

```
<header class="header vc_row-fluid vc_col-sm-12">
<div class="top-header vc_col-sm-12">
<div class="logo shadows vc_col-sm-3">
<a href="Default.aspx"><img src="images/layout/check1.png" width="230" height="69" alt="Dubai Exporters" /></a></div>
<div class="menu-btn icon-menu-1"></div>

<div class="header_search"><div class="search sb-search" id="sb-search">
    <div class="gray-form">
<input type="text" name="s" class="footer_search_input" onclick="clearInput(this, 'Search');" value="Search" />
<input type="submit" name="search" class="btn btn-primary sb-search-submit" value="Search" />
        <span class="sb-icon-search">GO</span>
        </div>

</div></div>
<div class="header-search-body">
<div class="header-search-container">
<div class="header-search-form">
<div class="header-form-container" id="mydiv">
<div class="header-input-container"><span class="header-input-title">Keyword:</span>
     <input type="text" id="txtkeyword" name="s" runat="server" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="clearfix"></div></div>


    <div class="header-input-container"><span class="header-input-title">Category:</span>
    <input type="text" id="txtserach" list="browsers" name="myBrowser" runat="server" autocomplete="off" causesvalidation="false">
     <datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Automotive"/>
  <option value="Building and Interiors"/>
  <option value="Food, Kitchen and Hotel Supplies"/>
  <option value="Industrial and Machinery"/>
  <option value="Consumer and Household"/>
  <option value="Medical and Healthcare"/>
                     <option value="Printing , Packaging and Plastic"/>
                     <option value="IT / Telecom / Electronics"/>
                     <option value="Oil and Gas"/>
                     <option value="Power and Energy"/>
</datalist>




<div class="clearfix"></div></div>




<input type="hidden" id="header-post-type" value="gd_place">
        <asp:Button ID="Search" class="wpb_button wpb_btn-warning icon-search" style="top:0px;width:70px;height:70px;" Text="Search" runat="server" onclick="doit" OnClientClick="return checkLength();" UseSubmitBehaviour="false" CausesValidation="false" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
       function checkLength() {
           var textbox = document.getElementById('<%=txtkeyword.ClientID%>');
           var textbox1 = document.getElementById('<%=txtserach.ClientID%>');
           if (textbox.value.length < 3 && textbox1.value.length == 0) {
                alert("The entered input should be 3 or more than 3 characters");
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //window.onload = function () {
        //    var hideMe = document.getElementById('mydiv');
        //    document.onclick = function (e) {
        //        if (e.target.id !== 'mydiv') {
        //           // mydiv.style.display = 'none';
        //        }
        //    };
        //};

        $(function () {
            $("[id*=Search]").click(function (e) {
                $("[id*=mydiv]").attr('style', 'display:block');
            });

            $(document).click(function (e) {
                if (!$(e.target).is('[id*=Search]')) {
                    $("[id*=mydiv]").attr('style', 'display:none');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<a href="http://cohhe.com/demo/sky/sky-directory/gd-login/" class="header-add-property wpb_button wpb_btn-primary wpb_regularsize">Add Your Listing</a>

<div class="top-menu-container ">
<div class="menu-style"><ul id="menu-menu-2" class="header-menu gd-menu-z">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-1759"><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
        <%--<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1767"><a href="advertize.aspx">Advertise</a></li>--%>

<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1760"><a href="exhibition.aspx">Exhibitions</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1764"><a href="dubaiexhibitions.aspx">Trade Fairs in U.A.E</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1761"><a href="exhibition.aspx">Trade Fairs Worldwide</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1762"><a href="addexhibition.aspx">Add Your Event</a></li>
<%--<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1765"><a href="http://cohhe.com/demo/sky/sky-directory/right-sidebar/">Right sidebar</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1763"><a href="http://cohhe.com/demo/sky/sky-directory/left-sidebar/">Left sidebar</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1766"><a href="http://cohhe.com/demo/sky/sky-directory/typography-2/">Typography</a></li>--%>
</ul>
</li>
<%--<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1767"><a href="http://cohhe.com/demo/sky/sky-directory/blog/">Subscribe</a></li>--%>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1768"><a href="member_benefits.aspx">Memberships</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1768"><a href="aboutus.aspx">About us</a></li>
    <%--<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1768"><a href="http://cohhe.com/demo/sky/sky-directory/contact/">Contact</a></li>--%>
</ul></div> </div>




<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<%--<div class="header-background-img"><img src="//cohhe.com/demo/sky/sky-directory/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/header_bg1.jpg" alt="Header bg" /></div>--%>
    <div class="header-search-container">
<div id="main_header_bg">
<style type="text/css" media="all">#main_header_image { background: url('images/header02.jpg'); height:150px; background-size: cover !important; background-position: 100% !important; }</style> 

</div>
<div id="main_header_image"></div>


</div>
</header>
```

Comment: Side note: i'm sure somebody smarter than me can perform a XSS on this site, I'd look into it OP, you're not encoding your search string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve with the class names.

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
   if(e.target != $(".sb-icon-search")[0]  && (e.target.parentElement.parentElement != $(".header-form-container")[0])){
       $(".header-search-body")[0].style.display = 'none';
     }
});

$(".header_search").click(function (e) {
     $(".header-search-body")[0].style.display = 'block';
});
```

it will be more easy way, if you use id instead of class names

Comment: ....search panel goes if clicked outside ..now the issue is that there is header-input-container for keyword and category..so when user try to enter any input,search panel goes.

Comment: ...Thats Worked Perfectly...Thank u so much...:)

Answer (score 1):

My impression is that **if** condition is the root cause.

```
if (!$(e.target).is('[id*=Search]')) {...}
```

Can you try with below condition.

```
var $box = $('[id*=mydiv]');
//Condition to check if the target is the div or any of its children
// if false then hide the modal
if ($box.has(event.target).length == 0 && !$box.is(event.target) && !$('[name="search"]').is(event.target)) {
    $box.attr('style', 'display:none');
}
```

Comment: @santosh..it dint worked..after clicking on go,search panel appears but when i click on input type of keyword,it goes.When i click on go again,search panel does not come.

Comment: @santosh...now after clicking on go...search panel does not appears.

Answer (score 1):

First remove/rename class 'header-search-container' that you have used for header background (its used twice). 
Then add event listeners or conditions on txtkeyword, textsearch and Search button.
Example:

```
 // this will hide the search div
    $(document).click(function (e) {
                var id = e.target.id;
                if(id !== 'ctl00_Search' && id !== 'ctl00_txtkeyword' && id !== 'ctl00_txtserach') {
                      $('.header-search-container')[0].style['display']='none';
                }
            });
```

Comment: ....i tried above javascript....so when i click on go button,search panel appears and when i click outside anywhere,it goes...only issue is that when i am trying to enter keyword or category,search panel goes...

Comment: @chetankambli did you first remove your jquery display none code ?

Comment: @rishabh...i removed the other div class..still the problem persists

Comment: @chetankambli I tried the same code on your website in the browser console and its working fine for me. Which browser are you using ?

Comment: @rishabh...can you able to enter keyword or category?

Comment: bcz whenever i am trying to enter keyword or category ,search panel goes

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the click event is propagated up the dom, and then perform a click on the parent elements.

To prevent that you should return false on the eventhandlers:

```
$(function () {
    $("[id*=Search]").click(function (e) {
        $("[id*=mydiv]").attr('style', 'display:block');
        return false;
    });

    $(document).click(function (e) {
        if (!$(e.target).is('[id*=Search]')) {
            $("[id*=mydiv]").attr('style', 'display:none');
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: ..i tried above javascript..  after clicking on go button,search panel does not comes.